# How to convert the output into a single line

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
#python
n = int(input().strip())
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

rev=arr[::-1]
for i in range(n):
    final=0
    final+=rev[i]
    print(final)
```

Given an array of integers, print the elements in reverse order as a single line of space-separated numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `input()` many times which is not required, also you can use the `join` function with `" "` separator to print all the elements of array in one line. Please note that `join` expects all elements as `str` so you will have to `map` it back to `str`, so it's better to avoid the `map` to `int` at the initial stage as we will have to `map` it back to `str`
Here is one of the approach:

```
n = input("Enter the sequence of numbers: ").strip()
arr = n.split()
print (" ".join(arr[::-1]))
```

Output:

```
Enter the sequence of numbers: 1 3 5 7 9
9 7 5 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

u may use join method for concat string sequences

but in your case u need to transform integers to string type

in the end code will be like this:
`reversed_string = ' '.join(map(str, rev))`